# Need to understand the behavoir of prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript

This code results default value of ISBN number (i.e 55555)from the prototype.As expected.

```
 function Book()
 {
    alert('construct called !!!');
 }
 Book.prototype={
    ISBN:55555
 };
 var book=new Book();
 alert(book.ISBN);
```

But following code result the alert message with 'undefined' test

```
function Book()
{
alert('construct called !!!');
}

function Book(isbn)
{
this.ISBN=isbn;
}
Book.prototype={
ISBN:55555
};
var book=new Book();
alert(book.ISBN);
```

This also should have resulted the default value(i.e. 55555) need to understand why is this behavior.

Comment: That's because you are calling the constructor without passing a value so `isbn` is `undefined`. Why do you expect it to be `55555` when you have reset the property with an `undefined` value?

Comment: Why would it have the value `55555` by default? You’ve explicitly set the `ISBN` property to `isbn` which is `undefined` (`this.ISBN=isbn;`) when you called the constructor.

Comment: In JavaScript you cannot overload functions. You define Book function and right after that you overwrite it with another version. Note that when you call new Book() without any parameters, second Book function is called, first simply does not exist anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your constructor `Book` executes, the first argument it finds is undefined and it assigns that to `this.ISBN`.

So, perhaps confusingly, book.ISBN contains [the primitive value undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), as opposed to not being defined at all.

When book.ISBN is called, because this primitive found in book instance itself, the interpreter never traverses up the prototype chain.

If you want to code to fallback to the value in prototype you will have to explicitly check for undefined:

```
function Book(isbn)
{
  if (isbn !== undefined) this.ISBN=isbn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining.